# Outcome of one dropdown menu determined by two

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, drop-down-menu

Here is a gender dropdown menu which determines the uniform cost.

```
 <p>Gender:
<select required name="gender" onchange="calc(this.id, 'uniform')"   id="gender">
<option value="0" >Select...</option>
<option value="male">Male</option>
<option value="female">Female</option>
</select> <p>
```

Cost of uniform drop down menu

```
<p>Cost of Uniform:
<select  required name="uniform"   id="uniform">
</select><p>
```

Here is my javascript code for the dependable Gender and uniform

```
<script>
function calc(u1,u2){

var u1 = document.getElementById(u1);
var u2 = document.getElementById(u2);
u2.innerHTML = "";
if (u1.value == "male"){
var optionArray = ["|","24300|N24,300"];
}
else  if (u1.value == "female"){
var optionArray = ["|","26400|N26,400"];
}
for(var option in optionArray){
var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
var newOption = document.createElement("option");
newOption.value = pair[0];
newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
u2.options.add(newOption);
}
}
</script>
```

Class (Year) drop down menu.

```
<p>Class:
<select required name="childClass" onchange="childClass(this.id, 'schoolFees')" id="childClass">
<option value="0" >Select...</option>
<option value="prenursery">Pre Nursery</option>
<option value="nursery">Nursery</option>
<option value="reception">Reception</option>
<option value="year1">Year One</option>
<option value="year2">Year Two</option>
<option value="year3">Year Three</option>
<option value="year4">Year Four</option>
<option value="year5">Year Five</option>
<option value="year6">Year Six</option>
</select>
<p>
```

School fees dropdown menu which depends on students class selected

```
<p>School Fees:
<select required name="schoolFees"   id="schoolFees"> 
</select>
```

Javascript for the class and school fees dependable dropdown. I am sure there is a shorther method but this still works.

```
<script>
function childClass(s1,s2){
   var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
   var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
 s2.innerHTML = "";
 if (s1.value == "prenursery"){
    var optionArray = ["|","145000|N145,000"];
 }
 else  if (s1.value == "nursery"){
    var optionArray = ["|","145000|N145,000"];
 }
 else  if (s1.value == "reception"){
    var optionArray = ["|","147000|N147,000"];
 }
 else  if (s1.value == "year1"){
    var optionArray = ["|","149000|N149,000"];
 }
 else  if (s1.value == "year2"){
    var optionArray = ["|","149000|N149,000"];
 }
 else  if (s1.value == "year3"){
    var optionArray = ["|","149000|N149,000"];
 }
 else  if (s1.value == "year4"){
    var optionArray = ["|","149000|N149,000"];
 }
 else  if (s1.value == "year5"){
    var optionArray = ["|","149000|N149,000"];
 }
 else  if (s1.value == "year6"){
    var optionArray = ["|","149000|N149,000"];
 }
 for(var option in optionArray){
     var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
     var newOption = document.createElement("option");
     newOption.value = pair[0];
     newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
     s2.options.add(newOption);
 }
 }
</script>
```

How can I make the class(year) and gender dropdown determine the value in uniform dropdown. For example. If I select female and year 4 I should get a different value in dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this https://jsfiddle.net/egq427g0/3/

I've modified the `childClass` to act accordingly the selection of `Gender` and `Class`

At the end of `childClass` calling `calc` function to reset uniform if 0 is selected in `Class`

Comment: That was awesome, Perfect. I will carefully study the code. I was even able to add the total to it. But I keep getting a NaN at the result. [link] https://jsfiddle.net/aayLrpz2/

Comment: Nothing wrong in your function, in jsfiddle it works little bit different. I've changed `function updateFee` to `window.updateFee = function()`. Please check here https://jsfiddle.net/aayLrpz2/1/

Comment: Hello @Kumar after checking I realized that once you select Gender, Class and Uniform the total still shows NaN until you select school fees then it starts to add up at the total.

Comment: I think the problem is selecting the initial value (Uniform) to reflect in the total sum.